# pandas dataFrame : i'd like to 'uniformize' values

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, I couldn't find a proper english way to put my request, therefore it might have been answered before but I couldn't find what I need. Please forgive me if there's already an answer for this...

So I have "hours" stored in a pd.DataFrame as follow:
1454
1621
and so on (they are 14:54 and 16:21)

problem :
some of them are 953 (for 09:53).

question :
how could I "autocomplete" these so that they are four digits long, containing zeroes (i'd like the above to be 0953, and additionnaly 23 to be 0023).

I was considering converting the number into strings, checking if they have less than 4 caracters, and adding a 0 at the beginning if not, but surely there must be a more pythonic way to do this ?

Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day !

Comment: "Uniformize" is the proper term, but I don't think you are wanting to change *values*; you want to uniformize their *representation*. (And, as you noted, Python's representation of integers does not allow leading zeroes.)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But I don't know how (or actually I could do it, but I'm looking for a clean and concise way to do it, rather than putting together a 10-15 lines function that would probably not be "pythonic")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to have a string column, and then you can use zfill:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1453, 923, 24, 1250], columns=['time'])
df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4)


#0    1453
#1    0923
#2    0024
#3    1250
#Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice answer - was unaware of zfill!

Comment: perfect, exactly what I was looking for as it takes care of both cases (0923 and 0024) ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

To add 0 at the beginning, the type must be string. If the column names is `hours`, start with

```
df.hours = df.hours.astype(str)
```

Now you can conditionally add a 0 to the beginning of shorter entries:

```
short = df.hours.str.len() < 4
df.hours.loc[short] = '0' + df.hours.loc[short]
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hours': [123, 3444, 233]})
df.hours = df.hours.astype(str)
short = df.hours.str.len() < 4
df.hours.loc[short] = '0' + df.hours.loc[short]
>>> df
    hours
0   0123
1   3444
2   0233
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is just me, but I firmly believe all dates manipulations should be done through `datetime`, not strings, so I would recommend some thing as follow:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4).apply(lambda x: x[:2] + ':' + x[2:]))
df['time_str'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%I-%M')
```